# Relationship of two generalizations of the real/complex calculus

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

On the one hand, one has the various functional calculi from Operator Algebras.  The continuous functional calculus for C* algebras, the bounded borel functional calculus for Von Neumann Algebras, the analytic one for Banach algebras.

On the other hand, one has the notions of integral and derivative (analyticity too, etc.) as the usual definitions for Banach-space-valued functions.  (There are the Bochner integrals, as well as the Riemann integral for the continuous case.)

Are these two things related?  I often see the functional calculus denoted with integrals, so I don't know if that's suggestive.

Comment: Banach-space valued functions defined on, say, a measure space extends real analysis. But what do you mean by generalization in the case of functional calculus? A functional calculus is a *-homomorphism from an algebra of functions to, say, an abelian $C^*$-subalgebra. (That integral you see is actually a $C^*$-map.) Seems to me they are different contexts.

Comment: @Michael Well, here is one way I could relate the two theorys above.  This will be a relationship among the Bochner integral (or my conception of it given the little that I know about it) with the Von Neumann algebra functional calculus with bounded Borel.  The latter furnishes a projection-valued measure, and to obtain $f(T)$ when T is normal, I integrate $f$ on $sp(T)$ against the projection valued measure, in the sense that it is obtainable as a norm limit of projection-valued simple functions by the usual arguments...

Comment: On the other hand, the theory of Bochner integrals tells me what to do in the dual situation.  I now have a measurable (whatever that means) operator-valued (say) f, and a classical $[0, \infty]$ valued measure, and the Bochner integral tells me how to integrate in this situation.  So in a sense, these two theories can be viewed as dual aspects of integration theory.  Can the other functional calculi be viewed as integration?  Are there deeper relationships even in the VNA case?

Comment: I see what you're saying: integration of scalar-valued function against an operator-valued measure vs. integration of operator-valued function against a scalar-valued measure. But this "duality" seems superficial. I'd be interested to know if there's anything more to it myself.